# Did anybody use WS-AtomicTransaction protocol to propagate transactions in WCF over the Internet?

Tags: transactions, wcf, wshttpbinding, wsat

Just curious, did anybody use WS-AT protocol to propagate transactions in WCF over the Internet in production(wsHttpBinding)?
Is it hard to deploy/support? 
Is it a good approach to keep a WS-AT port open?
Or maybe it is better to have a custom solution to support transactions? What do u think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have not used it.

Main reason is that we do not think that it is a good idea.

The problem is that you are then allowing a client on the internet to take a lock on your system. What happens if the client looses connection? You then have locks on your system that must wait for a timeout.

You reduce the scalability of the system and leave it open to denial of service attacks.